# BehaviorRelay/Variable slow RxDataSources if a lot of data in UITableview

Tags: rxdatasources

Using RxDataSources I have a UITableView with a lot of sections and cells. When I search and replace the data with a new data source, my UI is blocked.

I have tried throttle and debounce, but if I search at the 'right' moment, then the UI still gets blocked for 1-2 sec.

Anyway I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that too many animations were done at the same time. I used decideViewTransition to decide when it should animate.